# GZIP включено, а PageSpeed не видит этого. Как исправить?

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер, pagespeed-insights, gzip, firebug

На сайте включено сжатие GZIP, а Google PageSpeed все равно пишет, что необходимо включить его. В чем может быть проблема?

**Вот скриншот в фаербаге, что сжатие включено:**
[image: файрбаге]

**Вот скриншот из Pagespeed:**
[image: скриншот из Pagespeed]

Проблема возникла на этом сайте - https://semkeys.ru/

Comment: есть gzip `curl -k -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -I https://semkeys.ru/blog/klasterizacziya-semanticheskogo-yadra/`

Comment: нет gzip `curl -k -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" -I https://semkeys.ru/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Будем исправлять.

Answer (score 0):

Решается добавлением настроек для gzip в конфиге nginx в секцию server

```
server {
...
gzip on;
gzip_comp_level 5;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_static on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript  application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
...
}
```